# Vector Norm on Complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

How can we define a vector norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$ that is not an l$_p$-norm?
I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take, for instance, $\bigl\lVert(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n)\bigr\rVert=\lvert z_1\rvert+2\lvert z_2\rvert+\cdots+n\lvert z_n\rvert$.

Comment: But isn't norm a function from a vector space V(in this case $\mathbb{C}^n$)  to $\mathbb{R}$. What you have defined will be V*V->$\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I solved your problem in the case in which $n=2$ because I thought that that would be enough to understand how to do it in the general case. I've edited my answer.